# How can I prevent jQuery smartWizard from moving to the next step on enter press?

Tags: javascript, jquery, smart-wizard

I have tried this code but it is not working.

```
var wizardForm = $('#form');

wizardForm.on('keyup keypress', function(e) {
  var code = e.keyCode || e.which;
  if (code == 13) { 
    e.preventDefault();
    return false;
  }
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This [article](https://pranabeshchand.wordpress.com/2015/10/13/how-to-prevent-enter-keypress-to-submit-a-web-form/) solved my queestion:

```
$(window).keydown(function(event){
    if(event.keyCode == 13) {
    event.preventDefault();
    return false;
    }
});
```